# Why someone else push on my repo?

Tags: git, github

I forked this repo https://github.com/olilarkin/wdl-ol, making "my own": https://github.com/Nowhk/WDL-Nowhk

Now I see that some other user has been pull on this repo: https://github.com/Nowhk/WDL-Nowhk/commits/master

(well, in fact marcodallapiazza is me with another account). But how I was able to do so? Only Nowhk (or contributors) should be able to send updates from local machines... no?

Comment: Did you do the commits and push them, and you are only confused by the username?

Comment: Yes. I did commit and sync (push) from GitHub VS extension. This for example https://github.com/Nowhk/WDL-Nowhk/commit/95160cca2aafa1d391f2805397931fcaee74c737

Comment: What is the output of `git config user.name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you did the commits and pushed them to GitHub. You are only confused about the username you are seeing.

The username and email you are seeing next to your commits are not used for authentication. Git and GitHub do not care what you enter there. You can even change your username and email for every commit you make.

Only when you push/sync you need to authenticate to GitHub. If authentication succeeds, any commits you push will appear on GitHub. No matter what the author information of the commits says.

Comment: No @markzzz, the name and email you have set when committing is written to the commit and does not change. Then you connect to GitHub and push those commits. The user with which you connect to GitHub for pushing needs the right to push, but that has nothing to do with whom committed. You can even create a commit with me as author information and / or committer information and push that to GitHub.

Comment: Yes, as I said, I can commit with "bitch84" and than push with real/owner repo account. But it will be displayed "bitch84" than?

Answer (score 0):

Opening a pull request does not mean your original repository is going to get affected. Basically, someone who opens a request will simply be able to propose changes to the owner, so your work remains intact until you accept the changes or unless the other owner is a collaborator.
This link may be useful-
https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/

> well, in fact marcodallapiazza is me with another account). But how I
>   was able to do so? Only Nowhk (or contributors) should be able to send
>   updates from local machines... no?

Actually you can do that- if you change the config.username and password details. So if you are currently signed in as say xyz, then you choose to sign in as abc, you will have to just change the config.username to abc.